# Websocket - Reestablish connection after sudden drop

Tags: websocket

I developed a small DB system that uses websocket connection.
Sometimes the connection may suddenly drop and not because of cable or electricity issue, the reason is unclear to me now.

I have added heartbeats to check for connection every 3 seconds, and on server side I giving 5 seconds connection timeout for a case of a sudden slow connectivity.

**THE PROBLEM:**
After the client side realize that the connection is lost, it trying to reconnect. SOMETIMES it works, but sometimes it repeatedly fail - perhaps out of open connections??? How come? I am trying to make sure the connection is absolutely closed before reconnecting. What I am doing wrong?!

JS source (partial):

```
EF.WS=new EF_WebSocketInterface();
function EF_WebSocketInterface() {
    var _=this,QS={_:0},QR={},ito,hb;
    window.onunload=function() {
         if(!_||!_.con) return;
         // send termination command to the server
    }
    _.Init=function(p,f) { Run(f); }
    function Run(f) {
        if(_.con&&_.con.readyState!==3) return setTimeout(Run,1,f);
        if(!hb) hb=setInterval(_.SMInt,3000,'-',''); // Heartbeat
    }
    try {
        _.con=new WebSocket('wss://'+document.domain+':'+/* port */+'/?C='+ /* credentials been checked as OK */+'&L=EN-US');
        _.con.onerror=function(e) { console.log(e); }
        _.con.onopen=function() { _.con.tmt=Date.now(); }
        _.con.onclose=function() { setTimeout(Run,1); } // immediate reconnection!
        _.con.onmessage=function(e) {
            var V=new FileReader(),C,I;
            _.con.tmt=Date.now(); // Any incomming messages from the server including the heartbeat are updating the time stamp!
            V.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
                V=V.result.replace(/\n/g,'').replace(/\r/g,'');
                if(V=='-') return; // ignore server heartbeat for processing.
                /* Message (command) processing */
            });
            V.readAsText(e.data);
        }
    }
    catch(e){ console.log(e); if(_.con) _.con.onclose(); }
}
/* This is the official function to send commands.
   This will register the message in special queue for a case connection lost, to resend them without repeated user interaction.

     Parameters:
     p = Command code
     c = Parameters content for command
     f = function callback to be done on message receive (optional)
     x = reserved for internal use
*/
_.SM=function(p,c,f,x) {
     var d=""+(QS._++); while(d.length<5) d="0"+d; QS[d]=[(x?"":EF.ON([p,c])),Date.now(),f]; _.SMInt((x?x:"A"),d);
}

/* This is internal command sender*/
_.SMInt=function(b,c) {
    /* Command preparation and message ID management */

    // Preparation for sending the message
    if(_.con&&_.con.readyState==1) 

        // If pass more than 5 seconds, the connection probably closed.
        if(_.con.tmt+5000<Date.now()) { _.con.close(); }
        else {
            // Sending of heartbeat to the server, also checking if has got any pending messages in queue since last failed session.
            if(b=='-') {
                if(ito) return; ito=1; var n=Object.keys(QS);
                for(var i=0 ; i<n.length ; i++) if(n[i]!=='_' && QS[n[i]][1]+5000<Date.now()) _.SMInt("C",n[i]);
                    ito=0;
                }
                try { _.con.send(new Blob([m],{type:'text/html',charset:'utf-8'}),{ binary:true }); }
                catch(e) { }
            }
    }
    _.Get=function(p,m,r,c) { _.SM(m,r,function(e) { _.xQ(p,EF.Data,e); c(); }); 
}
}
```

Full JS code available in https://www.crazygao.com/ef4

Server side PERL (partial):

```
Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
    listen => $ssl,
    silence_max=> 14400,
    tick_period => 1,
    on_tick => sub {
        my @l=keys %CON; # This is the main connections DB, each with its own properties
        my $i; my $j; my @m;

        $_TPC->[2]++; if($_TPC->[2]==5) { $_TPC->[2]=0; }
        if($_TPC->[2]==0) {
            for($i=0 ; $i<@l ; $i++) {
                # Resend pending messages in queue

                # If connection passed 10 seconds without any message, it is clearly lost: &CX is closing the connection and deleting the session from %CON.

                if($CON{$l[$i]}{"C"}) {
                    if($CON{$l[$i]}{"T"}+10<time()) { &CX($l[$i],($CON{$l[$i]}{"T"}+300<time())?1:0); }
                else { &SMInt($l[$i],'-',''); }
            }
            elsif($CON{$l[$i]} && $CON{$l[$i]}{"T"}+14400<time()) { &XX($l[$i]); }
        }
    },
    on_connect => sub {
        my($serv,$conn)=@_; my $cid;
        $conn->on(
            handshake => sub {
                my($conn,$handshake)=@_;
                my $nsn=$handshake->req->resource_name;
                my $ns=substr($nsn,4,index($nsn,'&L=')-4);
                $cid=($ns eq "")?int(rand(1000000000)):$ns;
                if(!defined $CON{$cid}) { $CON{$cid}={"QS"=>{"_"=>0},"QR"=>{},"T"=>time(),"L"=>substr($nsn,index($nsn,'&L=')+3)}; }
                elsif(defined $CON{$cid}{"C"}) { $CON{$cid}{"C"}->disconnect(); }
                $CON{$cid}{"C"}=$conn;
            },
            binary => sub {
                # for any incomming messages - update the active time stamp. 
                $CON{$cid}{"T"}=time(); my($c,$msg)=@_;

                # ignore client side heartbeat here
                if($msg eq '-') { return; } 

                # Process the message (command)
            },
            disconnect => sub {} # Nothing special to be done.
        );
    }
)->start;

sub CX {
    $CON{$_[0]}{"C"}->disconnect();
    delete $CON{$_[0]}{"C"}; if($_[1]==1 && $CON{$_[0]}{'U'} eq "") { &XX($_[0]); }
}
sub XX { delete $CON{$_[0]}; }
```

**NOTE:**
1. Credentials stored in client side as JS variable is not lost, unless the client will refresh the browser, but this is NOT the case.
2. The readystate variable checked on such "connection drop" still shows 1 - but message is NOT being forwarded to the server.
3. In repeated connectivity failue, if I refresh the browser and reconnect, it will work fine ( strange... ).
4. In PERL, I am using Net::Websocket::Server and IO::Socket::SSL, if it helps.

Is it possible that PERL command to disconnect from a connection takes longer to close?
Any ideas for the sudden connection drop or why I fail to reconnect will be appreciate.